# How to alter columnstore index in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to alter the index using sql query as below in SQL SERVER 2012

```
ALTER INDEX [missing_index_4716_4766] ON tblEmployee REBUILD WITH(ONLINE = ON)
```

But I am getting error as below -

> alter statement failed because the operation cannot be performed online on a table with a columnstore index. Perform the operation without specifying the ONLINE option or drop (or disable) the columnstore index before performing the operation using the ONLINE option.

Can anyone help me here like how I can alter column store index. I have gone through many article like[Alter Index MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) but I didn't get proper solution.

Comment: Would it be a suitable solution for you to just DROP the index and CREATE it again? If not, why?

Comment: Message is pretty clear, you can't rebuild your index on hot (online) if the table has a columnstore index. Either rebuild the index offline or disable the columnstore index (and re-enable afterwards).

Comment: Thanks All for your comment. I have a doubt like is this issue is happening only SQL server 2012 or with some other version of SQL as well?

Comment: The same above  ALTER query is working in one server and not working in another server. Any idea like why it is happening?